# Как вывести вектор типа list<pair<int,string>> на экран C++

Tags: c++, list, vector

Есть вот такой код

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<list <pair<int, string>>> myvector;
    list <pair<int, string>> help;
    pair<int,string> p;
    p.first = 0;
    p.second = "data";
    help.push_back(p);
    myvector.push_back(help);
}
```

я не могу вывести данные данного вектора на экран, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Типа

```
for(const auto& l: myvector)
    for(const auto& p: l)
        cout << p.first << "  " << p.second << endl;
```

?

Comment: Спасибо, всё напечаталось, не могли бы подробнее чуть-чуть объяснить, что в этих циклах происходит ?

Comment: В первом - перебираем все `list`ы в векторе, во втором - перебор `pair` в `list`е. Последняя строка - вывод полей `pair`.